# Extract a sub-string out of a variable's value

Tags: shell-script, string

I have a string in the form of `segment_78787` which is stored in a variable called `$ID` in my shell script. I need to get the second part "78787" and assign it to another variable.

I tried like

```
batchname=`ID|cut -d_ -f1`
```

It didn't gave me any result.

Answer (score 4):

If your shell supports it, you can use the expansion

```
batchname=${ID##*_}
```

or even

```
batchname=${ID#*_}
```

The first form removes all characters up to and including the rightmost underscore and the second form removes all characters up to and including the leftmost underscore. In your particular example, both forms are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
batchname=`echo $ID | cut -d_ -f2`
```